# Access IPV4 address of local linux machine

Tags: haskell

I'm attempting to use this library to access IP :

http://jacob.stanley.io/2010/08/12/ip-addresses-and-mac-addresses-in-haskell/

src :

```
import Network.Info

    main = do
        ns <- getNetworkInterfaces
        mapM_ (putStr . showInterface) ns

    showInterface n = name n ++ "\n"
                   ++ "  IPv4: " ++ show (ipv4 n) ++ "\n"
                   ++ "  IPv6: " ++ show (ipv6 n) ++ "\n"
                   ++ "  MAC:  " ++ show (mac n) ++ "\n"
```

How can I just access the IPv4 address via ghci in a var ?

something like :

```
 let ipv4 = filterIpV4Address(ns)
```

`ns` is of type `ns :: [NetworkInterface]` and contains all the network interfaces. I'm new to Haskell and do not understand this code.

How is variable "n" set in line `showInterface n = name n ++ "\n"`

Is it somehow set at line `mapM_ (putStr . showInterface) ns` ?

Update :

```
Prelude Network.Info Main> ns <- getNetworkInterfaces
Prelude Network.Info Main> ns

    [NetworkInterface {name = "Local Area Connection", ipv4 = 169.254.166.181, ipv6
    = fe80:0:0:0:94d4:87b2:7435:a6b5, mac = e8:11:32:d4:bf:04},NetworkInterface {nam
    e = "Wireless Network Connection", ipv4 = 192.168.1.12, ipv6 = fe80:0:0:0:b593:3
    47d:11d0:916f, mac = 00:1b:b1:28:a7:96},NetworkInterface {name = "Bluetooth Netw
    ork Connection", ipv4 = 169.254.131.172, ipv6 = fe80:0:0:0:6cc5:4071:a29b:83ac,
    mac = 90:a4:de:9c:a2:7a},NetworkInterface {name = "VirtualBox Host-Only Network"
    , ipv4 = 192.168.56.1, ipv6 = fe80:0:0:0:91e2:7d75:e6f7:d90f, mac = 0a:00:27:00:
    00:00},NetworkInterface {name = "Loopback Pseudo-Interface 1", ipv4 = 127.0.0.1,
     ipv6 = 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, mac = 00:00:00:00:00:00},NetworkInterface {name = "Loca
    l Area Connection* 12", ipv4 = 0.0.0.0, ipv6 = fe80:0:0:0:0:100:7f:fffe, mac = 0
    0:00:00:00:00:00},NetworkInterface {name = "isatap.home", ipv4 = 64.3.66.5, ipv6
     = fe80:0:0:0:0:5efe:c0a8:10c, mac = 00:00:00:00:00:00},NetworkInterface {name =
     "isatap.{7F25AE4D-EDF3-491F-ADED-642C194C94D9}", ipv4 = 0.0.0.0, ipv6 = fe80:0:
    0:0:0:5efe:c0a8:3801, mac = 00:00:00:00:00:00}]
```

So how to extract value : 192.168.1.12 ?

Comment: please do not edit your question to ask new questions - this is not the way stackoverflow works, just ask a new question and/or see if something like this has been answered before. - btw you are just working with a list after `ns <- getNetworkInterfaces` so study the list functions in the standard library (Prelude), and if you are new search for `record-syntax` which might provide some answers.

Comment: @epsilonhalbe did I not just expand on original question ? I originally asked how to access my local ip, and then in edited version I ave output of  function and ip value that I wish to extract. But I admit there are at least more than 1 questions in my post. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the documentation you get the definition of `NetworkInterface`

```
data NetworkInterface = NetworkInterface { name :: String
                                         , ipv4 :: IPv4
                                         , ipv6 :: IPv6
                                         , mac :: MAC}
```

this tells you that if you want to access `name` etc. you have accessor function of the same name, with the type signature `name :: NetworkInterface -> String` (analogously for the others) - thus if you want to extract the name from a list of network interfaces you are looking for something like `?? :: (NetworkInterfaces -> String) -> [NetworkInterfaces] -> [String]` which is a special case of this type signature `?? :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]` put it into [hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%28a+-%3E+b%29+-%3E+%5Ba%5D+-%3E+%5Bb%5D) and you see a function called `map` as the first result.

So in order to collect the network names you only need to `map names ns`.

But if you want to apply this functions to the result of `getNetworkInterfaces` there is this `IO` indicator that is not fitting into this type signature; but there exists a function called `fmap` - a more general version of the function `map` we already saw that can help us.

`fmap` takes a container (in this case `IO` and a function that works on containees and applies the function in a sensible way to said containees, (btw. all containers that supply such a function are called `Functors`).

So in order to get your names from `getNetworkInterfaces` directely you need to put in your ghci:

```
Prelude> ns <- fmap (map name) getNetworkInterfaces
```

or with 'backtick-syntax'

```
Prelude> ns <- map name `fmap` getNetworkInterfaces
```

and if you `import Control.Applicative` you get this very handy infix operator `<$>` that lets you write it as `map name <$> getNetworkInterfaces`

## EDIT

`showInterface` is actually a function - its type signature which is omitted - is `showInterface :: NetworkInterface -> String` which means it takes a `NetworkInterface` and produces a `String`. So the `n` is actually a network interface which has (by the data declaration I posted) 4 accessor functions for getting `name`, `ipv4`, `ipv6`, and `mac`. Unfortunately the `putStr` function which produces output to `stdout` has type signature `String -> IO ()` which would only work for `name` which is already a `String`, to get the remaining 3 to work we have to use haskell's `toString()`-method which is called `show`, the rest that `showInterface` does is stitching `String`s together with the `++` operator. (Sidenote: `(++)` stitches together two lists of the same type and `String`s are just `[Char]` = list of `Char`)

So what does `mapM_` do at last - it works very analogous to `map` (hence the name), but it allows for side effects to happen and fortunately enough printing to stdout (with `putStr`) is such a side effect. Note that there are two functions very similar `mapM` and `mapM_` the underscore you might see from time to time in haskell-land indicates that something is thrown away/not needed, in this case the result - where in this case `mapM` would produce a `IO [()]`, `mapM_` just forgets the list and produces `IO ()` (speak IO unit - which you can think of `void` in C-like languages, my mnemonic is `void` has io in it but with something around to hide it and spelled in the wrong order).

And incidentally the type signature for `main` which is also omitted is `main :: IO ()` which fits exactly to the `mapM_`.

Comment: thanks for this detail, will take me a few re-reads. But I don't understand how to access the IP address of hostmachine. Should I be able to use something like "ns ipv4" ? I have updated question

Comment: it would not work this way `ns ipv4` is a list applied (whitespace = function application) to a function which is not correct - in order to get the first element of a list you would need a function called `head :: [a] -> a`. So `ipv4 (head ns)` would be a correct thing. if you are new to haskell and having problems with lists I can recomment the respective chapters in learnyouahaskell.com

Comment: the chapter on record syntax http://learnyouahaskell.com/making-our-own-types-and-typeclasses#record-syntax and for list handling http://learnyouahaskell.com/starting-out#an-intro-to-lists - PS: I like this chapter simply for the caterpillar